# How to build `requests_cache` cache.sqlite in a different directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, python-requests

I have a nice script here that is meant to print the HTML of a webpage. If I execute it like `python3 main.py`,  it creates a `webpage_cache.sqlite` in the current directory. If run it in interactive by `exec(open("main.py").read())`, it does not create it in the current directory. is there any way I can make this script run and place it at a custom location so I don't get lots of extra files, and rarely caching, as it won't find my cache? The script is below:

```py
import requests
import requests_cache

requests_cache.install_cache('webpage_cache')

# URL of the webpage to fetch
url = input("What URL should I fetch?")

# Make a GET request to the webpage
response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the response was retrieved from the cache
if response.from_cache:
    print('Retrieved from cache')
else:
    print('Fetched from website')

# Print the HTML content of the webpage
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1: Absolute path

You can use either an absolute path, or a path relative to `main.py`:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from requests_cache import CachedSession

# Absolute
cache_path = Path('~/webpage_cache.sqlite').expanduser()

# Relative to current file
cache_path = Path(__file__) / 'webpage_cache.sqlite'

session = CachedSession(cache_path)
print(f'Using cache location: {session.cache.db_path}')

url = input('What URL should I fetch?')
response = session.get(url)

print(f'Retrieved from cache: {response.from_cache}')
print(response.text)
```

## Option 2: System cache dir

You can also use your platform-specific cache directory with the `use_cache_dir` option:

```py
from requests_cache import CachedSession

session = CachedSession('webpage_cache', use_cache_dir=True)
print(f'Using cache location: {session.cache.db_path}')
...
```

## Docs

There are some more details on handling cache files here: https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/files.html